# De-Moivre Theorem

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers

I have a solution for the following de-moivre question and I have a doubt regarding it

$(\cos7\theta + i\sin7\theta)  = (\cos\theta +isin\theta)^7=$
$$
 = \cos^7\theta + 7\cos^6\theta(i\sin\theta) + 21\cos^5\theta(i\sin\theta)^2 + 35\cos^4\theta(i\sin\theta)^3 + $$$$+35\cos^3\theta(i\sin\theta)^4 + 21\cos^2\theta(i\sin\theta)^5 + 7\cos\theta(i\sin\theta)^6 + (i\sin\theta)^7
$$
Kindly explain how 21, 35 came in the solution, and also the whole part is expanded?

Comment: This is a standard binomial expansion - do you know anything about those or about Pascal's Triangle?

Comment: Consider using \sin\theta \and \cos\theta to get $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$ instead of $sin\theta$ and $cos\theta$. You can also put whole expressions in "math mode": 25\sin\theta + 15\cos\theta between dollar signs will give $25\sin\theta + 15\cos\theta$

Comment: @MarkBennet No, i dont know about those things, can you explain?

Comment: If you look up Pascal's Triangle you will find your coefficients. $21$ comes, for example from the number of ways of choosing cosine twice out of seven factors (the other five being sine - the whole thing is a seventh power, the product of seven identical factors, if written out in full as a product). Pascal's triangle tabulates such numbers. There is a great deal of rich material to explore e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle. You won't get far with de Moivre without knowing about these numbers, which are also called binomial coefficients amongst other things.